# Is chown user:group file the same as chgrp group file when assigning permissions to a group?

Tags: linux

If I use the command `chown username:groupname filename` to assign permissions to both a user and a group, does the command have the same results when executing `chgrp groupname filename`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since you specified a user with `chown`.

```
chown :groupname filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have elaborated. I meant does the inclusion of the group name have the same result as `chgrp` when I run the command `chown username:groupname filename`?

Comment: `chown` allows you to change user and/or group, yes.